# HDMI Issue with Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme

Tags: dual-boot, hdmi

So I recently did a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and while the HDMI works fine with Windows, it doesn't at all with Ubuntu. The monitor I have is a Acer SB220Q by the way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thinkpad X1 Extreme HDMI port is wired up to the discrete GPU card (NVIDIA). You must be using the nvidia drivers to be able to use the port. If you are using the UHD 630 GPU, it is not possible to see the external HDMI port.